# discord.py help command using discord components

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am revamping my help command using the "SelectOption" component of the discord-components library. Here is the code :-

```
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
  embed_main = discord.Embed(title = "Help!", color = discord.Color.random())
  await ctx.send(
    embed=embed_main,
    components = [
      Select(placeholder="Make A Choice!", options=[SelectOption(emoji="", label="Moderation", value="A", description="Get Help On Moderation")])
      ]
  )
  interaction = await bot.wait_for("select_option", check=lambda i: i.component[0].value == "A")
  await interaction.respond(
    embed = discord.Embed(title = " Moderation Commands", color = discord.Color.random())
    embed.add_field(name = "Type `tnj.help <command name> for more info on it", value = "`kick`\n `ban`\n `unban`\n `mute`\n `unmute`\n `purge`")
    )
```

Every thing works but it gives a syntax error and says "expected ')'" on this line :-

```
embed.add_field(name = "Type `tnj.help <command name> for more info on it", value = "`kick`\n `ban`\n `unban`\n `mute`\n `unmute`\n `purge`")
```

I don't know what im doing wrong, any help would be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: In Python, assignments are purely statements and cannot be used where an expression is expected. `embed = discord.Embed(title = " Moderation Commands", color = discord.Color.random())` is a statement, but is being used where an expression is expected (as an argument to the `interaction.respond()` call). This causes a `SyntaxError`. Further, if you meant to use those two lines as two arguments to the call, you would need to delimit them with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess at your intention, but this code may be closer to what you want to do:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title = " Moderation Commands", color = discord.Color.random())
await interaction.respond(
    embed,
    embed.add_field(name = "Type `tnj.help <command name> for more info on it", value = "`kick`\n `ban`\n `unban`\n `mute`\n `unmute`\n `purge`")
    )
```

This assumes that the value returned by `embed.add_field()` is suitable as a second argument for the call to `interaction.respond()`.

Comment: I understood what you mean to say, but where do I build the embed then? Doing what you suggested gives `embed is not defined`. If I do something like


 `await interaction.respond(
  
 embed = discord.Embed(title = " Moderation Commands", color = discord.Color.random()),

 embed.add_field(name = "Type tnj.help <command name> for more info on it", value = "kick\n ban\n unban\n mute\n unmute\n purge")
    )`  


It gives `positional argument cannot appear after a keyword arguments`

Comment: There is no reason why it should give `embed is not defined`. The assignment appears before your async call to `interaction.respond()`, so it should absolutely be defined. Are you sure you are using the exact code I posted, and that the code surrounding it is correct? Try to remove code until you have the bare minimum (with the code snippet in my answer) and then see if it works. The other snippet you posted in your comment will not work. `embed = ...` when used as an argument is a keyword argument, and must come after positional args (those without `=`).